# apply() returning the same object

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand how Future works and I came across its `apply()`. The api says this about the `apply()`

> Starts an asynchronous computation and returns a `Future` object with
>   the result of that computation

I wanted to understand it better by creating a simple object, whose apply will return the same object with modified fields. For example, consider the below code:

```
object Rough extends App {
  trait Sample

  object Sample {
    var x: Int = 0
    def apply[T](body: => T): String= {
      "Hello " + body
    }
  }

  val s: String = Sample.apply("World")

  print(s)
}
```

Right now the apply is returning a `String`. I want it to return `Sample[Int]`. More specifically, I want the `apply()` to return `Sample[Int]` where the Int value will be the length of String characters which was passed to the `apply()`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confused about a few unrelated Scala topics.

First off, `apply()` is just a method like any other.  It's only special in that the name can be omitted when it is invoked.  So `Sample()` is just a convenient shorthand for `Sample.apply()`.

Now if you want a method that returns the singleton object that it is attached to, just have it return `this`.

```
object Sample {   // create a singleton object
  var x: Int = 0
  def apply(s: String): Sample.type = {
    x = s.length  // save some data
    this          // return a reference to this object
  }
}

val samp = Sample("Hi there")  // invoke the 'apply()' method
samp.x            // get the saved data --> res0: Int = 8
```

Comment: And one more is that "returns a `Future` object" (or "a `Sample` object") does not mean it returns "the same object", i.e. the object defined by `object Future`, but an object which extends `trait Future[A]`.